# Creating threads on a JVM different than the one it is running

Tags: jvm, java-threads

I have a server which has two JVM's and I have a class which creates dummy threads.This runs on lets say JVM A.How can I create these threads on JVM B programatically.

After some research I came across http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/index.html. I am not sure if this can suffice my requirement.

Comment: *"not sure if this can suffice my requirement"* - This depends on your requirements, which are not quite clear to me. Yes, it is possible to create threads in different VM using Dynamic Attach API. But the clearer and more intuitive way would be to communicate through general RMI/RPC mechanism as @PeterLawrey mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You need JVM A to contact JVM B to tell it to start some threads. You will also need to pass any data JVM B need to run and possibly pass back any results.  A simple example is using RMI or RPC.